# How do i add support for playlist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need help adding support for playlist with this music bot.

I've been looking around a lot but have been unable to find any code related to mine and i don't wanna rewrite a new bot. I just need it to also work with playlist.

```
case 'play':
    if (usedCommandRecently4.has(message.author.id)) {
        message.reply("Your using this command to fast!");
    } else {
        function play(connection, message) {

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: "audioonly" }));

            server.queue.shift();

            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n Adding song to queue!");

            server.dispatcher.on("end", function () {
                if (server.queue[0]) {
                    play(connection, message);
                } else {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            })
        }

        if (!args[1]) {
            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n you need to provide a link!!");
            return;
        }

        if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n You must be in a voice channel to play music!");
            return;
        }

        if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }

        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);

        if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) 
            message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function (connection) {
                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: "audioonly" }));
                play(connection, message);
            })

        usedCommandRecently4.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            usedCommandRecently4.delete(message.author.id)
        }, 10000);
    }

    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes and fixed an error, tell me if this helps this time :

```
case 'play':
    if (usedCommandRecently4.has(message.author.id)) {
        message.reply("You're using this command to fast!");
    } else {
        function play(connection, message) {

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: "audioonly" }));

            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n Adding song to queue!");

            server.dispatcher.on("end", function () {
                server.queue.shift();

                if (server.queue[0]) { play(connection, message); }
                else {
                    connection.disconnect();
                    server.voiceChannel.leave();
                    delete servers[message.guild.id];
                }   
            });
        }

        if (!args[1]) {
            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n you need to provide a link!!");
            return;
        }

        if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n You must be in a voice channel to play music!");
            return;
        }

        if (!servers[message.guild.id]) {
         servers[message.guild.id] = { queue: [] };
        }

        var server = servers[message.guild.id];
        server.queue.push(args[1]);

        if (!message.guild.voice.connection) {
            server.voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
            server.voiceChannel.join().then(function (connection) {
                play(connection, message);
            });
        }

        usedCommandRecently4.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            usedCommandRecently4.delete(message.author.id)
        }, 10000);
    }

    break;
```